# Classic ASP and Youtube Player

Tags: asp-classic

Im looking for help as to what I need to do to be able to display the Youtube player.

The following code is fine if its a web page e.g. www.youtube.com but when I change the url to the Youtube player it displays the characters CWS and some other weird characters.

I've tried various Contenttype but had no joy.

Any suggestions appreciated, sorry its classic ASP but I rarely dip my toes into this side of things and its all I know and alas that is very little.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%  
response.ContentType="video/mpeg"
%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%      
url = "http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3" 
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 

xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "" 
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
Set xmlhttp = nothing
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `ContentType` shouldn't be anything but `text/html` (ie: don't change it).

You don't need to open fetch anything from Youtube. Just use add their embed code to your page as-is and it should work:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry should have explained I'm trying to run this as a proxy and the issue is streaming the Youtube video

Comment: NullUserException - The reason i want a proxy btw is I have a small business and want to restrict youtube access (bandwidth) but also enable access. 

There are alternatives I know but I wanted to see if I can do this as a proxy and control it via a front end app.

What I now find is if I call Youtube:

e.g. url = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMjsCf0uP10&feature=topvideos"

then I get the videos displayed fine when I test it via localhost but when I try it from my VPS the ad vdieos all run fine but the Youtube player is black with the words 
"an error occurred please try again later".

Comment: @Yummy Why exactly do you need a proxy?  If this is on a public facing website then the only bandwith cost to yourself is serving the HTML, proxying YouTube **vastly increases** your bandwith usage - it *does not* reduce it :-S  When a user accesses a web page with an embedded YouTube player it is them that incurs the bandwith cost of the video as their browser requests the video from YouTube not from yourself.  You only incur the cost to serve the HTML necessary for the embedded player.

Comment: youtube videos aren't mpegs, they're flash videos.  The mime type is video/x-flv .flv

Comment: @John Youtube actually stores videos in a variety of formats, including MP4, FLV, 3GP and webm